# Running Google Home On Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, raspberrypi, google, speakers, bluetooth-speaker

Good Day
I was wondering if I could install google home on ubuntu. I have seen people installing it on raspberry pi and on raspbian. I have a bluetooth speaker lying around and a Ubuntu system running servers. If anyone has an idea on how I could install or make it work kindly let me know. If for some reason google home is not an option, Alexa could work too. I just want to see if this is possible and maby get it working.
Thanks :)

Comment: Please give examples of "people installing it on Raspbian"...

Comment: Google Home is Android software. Look up how to use an Android Emulator in Ubuntu.

Comment: Google Assistant Unofficial Desktop Client: https://github.com/Melvin-Abraham/Google-Assistant-Unofficial-Desktop-Client

Comment: Better (and easier) to install as SNAP: https://snapcraft.io/g-assist

Comment: Let it be known that you can also install Alexa: `sudo snap install alexa --beta`

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Unofficial Desktop Client for Google Assistant](https://snapcraft.io/install/g-assist/ubuntu).
I use it to control a table lamp. :)

To install it run in the terminal:

```
sudo snap install g-assist
```

You may need to install Snap first. Snap is pre-installed and ready to go on all recent releases of Ubuntu. You don't need to do anything if you’re running Ubuntu 16.04 or later.
To install Snap, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet found a solution to installing Google Home app on Ubuntu. But have tried this:
https://medium.com/@freeyourdesktopblog/install-google-assistant-in-gnome-shell-48c155d8dd9b

This installs a Google assistant client and can do most of the actions like controlling linked devices,I have linked Google speakers and IKEA smarthub, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [Anbox](https://anbox.io/) that claims that it will run Google Play Store apps on Ubuntu. I've never tried it so can't claim that this will work but it's probably worth further research.